# flexible column comparison in data table r

Tags: r, function, data.table

I am trying to filter by comparing groups of columns with each other in a dynamic fashion.  Suppose I have the data base.

```
###########
#Setup data
###########

set.seed(2)
fill = data.table(n=1:7)
Tp=3

  for(t in 1:Tp){ 
     set(x = fill, j = paste0('prod1vint',t), value = sample(0:10,7))
  }

fill[1,paste0('prod1vint',3):=0]
fill[5,paste0('prod1vint',2):=0]
fill[5,paste0('prod1vint',3):=0]

for(t in 1:Tp){ 
  fill[,paste0('prod1vint',t,'prm'):=get(paste0('prod1vint',t))]
}


fill[1,paste0('prod1vint',1,'prm'):=0] 
fill[2,paste0('prod1vint',2,'prm'):=1]   
fill[5,paste0('prod1vint',3,'prm'):=1]  
fill[7,paste0('prod1vint',3,'prm'):=2]
```

The data table:

```
   n prod1vint1 prod1vint2 prod1vint3 prod1vint1prm prod1vint2prm prod1vint3prm
1: 1          2          9          0             0             9             0
2: 2          7          4          8             7             1             8
3: 3          5         10          9             5            10             9
4: 4          1          8          1             1             8             1
5: 5          6          0          0             6             0             1
6: 6          8          7          0             8             7             0
7: 7          0          0          6             0             0             2
```

By dynamic, I mean Tp can be an arbitrary integer.

I want to filter the following way:

For each t, e.g. `prod1vint{t}`, I want to compare to look at the "prm" version of it and check if it's not zero.  If it is not zero, then I only want to keep rows for which all `t'>t` vint are less than or equal to the pre-prime values and all lower elements `(t'<t)` are the SAME, e.g.

For each t.., if `prod1vint{t}!=0`, then

```
1. prod1vint{t'}prm <= prod1vint{t'} for t'>t
2. prod1vint{t'}prm == prod1vint{t'} for t'<t
```

For example, the following output should be displayed:

```
   n   prod1vint1 prod1vint2 prod1vint3 prod1vint1prm prod1vint2prm prod1vint3prm
1: 3          5         10          9             5            10             9
2: 4          1          8          1             1             8             1
3: 6          8          7          0             8             7             0
4: 7          0          0          6             0             0             2
```

(In case the X-Y problem...[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999582/how-to-check-whether-a-vector-is-lifo-decreasing) might help... I am trying to make sure each vector (prod1vint1,prod1vint2,prod1vint3) is LIFO decreasing to it's prime. Ignore this bit if it doesn't help.  My attempted solution involves coding various conditions such as the one above, which I am stuck on.)

Comment: i think you should reshape your data with `melt` to facilitate this.

Comment: Not sure how that helps

Answer (score 0):

Using melt as the comments suggest I would do it like this:

```
# this part is as replied from the question
set.seed(2)
fill = data.table(n=1:7)
Tp=3

for(t in 1:Tp){ 
  set(x = fill, j = paste0('prod1vint',t), value = sample(0:10,7))
}

fill[1,paste0('prod1vint',3):=0]
fill[5,paste0('prod1vint',2):=0]
fill[5,paste0('prod1vint',3):=0]

for(t in 1:Tp){ 
  fill[,paste0('prod1vint',t,'prm'):=get(paste0('prod1vint',t))]
}


fill[1,paste0('prod1vint',1,'prm'):=0] 
fill[2,paste0('prod1vint',2,'prm'):=1]   
fill[5,paste0('prod1vint',3,'prm'):=1]  
fill[7,paste0('prod1vint',3,'prm'):=2] 

# NEW CODE
fill.melt <- reshape2::melt(fill, id.vars = c('n'))

fill.melt$intpart <-  sapply(fill.melt$variable, 
                            function (x) 
                              {stringr::str_extract(gsub('prod1','',x),
                                                    '\\d')})


fill.melt$prmpart <-  ifelse(grepl('prm', fill.melt$variable), 'prm','noprm')
fill.cast <- reshape2::dcast(fill.melt, n+intpart ~ prmpart , value.var = 'value')
fill.cast <- as.data.table(fill.cast)

t=3


tmp <- fill.cast[
                 ((intpart >= t & prm <= noprm) | (intpart < t & prm == noprm)),]

ns <- unique(tmp$n)[table(tmp$n) == t]

fill[n %in% ns,]
```

Comment: do you know that `data.table` has much faster and more functional `melt/dcast` functions?

Comment: Absolutely, I am very fan of data.table, this is just a solution